# How to create a list of all ticked/non-ticked filter in an excel pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

This, I hope, is a really simple question but it might not be possible.

In excel, I have used multiple filters in a pivot table, I now want to create a list of the options ticked from the various filters.

How can I create a list/copy all the ticked (or un-ticked) boxes. I have around 800 filters with about 250 boxes ticked.

Comment: Is this for one field? e.g. perhaps you have a 'Customers' field, and have selected 250 customers out of 800?

Comment: This could be for a single filtered field... So yes your example works. I am only interested in 250 customers, so I filter for those 250, then I want to create a list of those 250.

Comment: You got me thinking... I could move that filtered field onto a row or column and then copy and paste that somewhere else and then move the filtered field back. A little messy but does sort of get me what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Manual approach:**

Select a cell in the PivotTable. Then from the PivotTable Tools>Analyze tab use the Select icon to select the entire PivotTable. Copy it and paste it somewhere else. Drag every field out of it, leaving just the Customers field in it as a Rows field. There's your list.

If you add a slicer, and connect it to both PivotTables, then any changes to the Customer field in your original Pivot will flow through to this new one.

**The VBA Approach:**

See my UDF at https://superuser.com/questions/1254703/add-slicer-selections-to-sheet-in-a-list-excel-vba/1255885#1255885

And if you want a way to 'recall' a filter, then check out my answer here: 
[Pivotfields multiple filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45718045/pivotfields-multiple-filter/45726720#45726720)