# Autofilter last used date in a pivot table

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I'm trying to auto-filter my pivot table based on the most recent date in my data and I came across the following code. However, when I try to execute it, I get a

> run-time error (1004 - Unable to set the Visible property of the PivotItem class)

on the line:  `pfiPivFldItem.Visible = False` Can someone help me with this?

```
Dim pfiPivFldItem As PivotItem
Dim dtmDate As Date

With Worksheets("Sheet2").PivotTables("Campaigns")
    .PivotCache.Refresh
    .ClearAllFilters

    With .RowRange
        dtmDate = Evaluate("MAX(IF(ISNUMBER(" & .Address(0, 0) & ")," & .Address(0, 0) & ",))")
    End With

    For Each pfiPivFldItem In .PivotFields("Date").PivotItems
        If pfiPivFldItem.Value = "(blank)" Then
            pfiPivFldItem.Visible = False
        Else
            pfiPivFldItem.Visible = (CDate(pfiPivFldItem.Value) = CLng(dtmDate))
        End If
    Next pfiPivFldItem
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have the error in the line you say? It would make sense to throw an error in pfiPivFldItem.Visible = (CDate(pfiPivFldItem.Value) = CLng(dtmDate)) since PivotItem.Visible is a boolean...
Feels like a typo and that you really want to set the Value, not the Visible property.

Comment: Hi a-burge, Thanks for your reply! When I try to execute the code, pfiPivFldItem.Visible = False is the line that is being highlighted. Can you please tell me what you would suggest to change in pfiPivFldItem.Visible = (CDate(pfiPivFldItem.Value) = CLng(dtmDate)) ? I'm not sure of the solution :/

Comment: @a-burge pfiPivFldItem.Visible is read/write, and will happily accept the evaluated answer of (CDate(pfiPivFldItem.Value) = CLng(dtmDate))

Comment: @Pret It may well be that (CDate(pfiPivFldItem.Value) will never equal CLng(dtmDate)) due to the issue/bug I outlined at http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2013/11/09/a-date-with-pivotitems/  . Suggest you step through the code and check what happens when the item you *think* should be visible is reached in that loop.

Comment: @jeffreyweir - Thank you so much for your detailed response! I'll step through the code like you suggested and will get back with the update.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common error I see when folk are trying to iterate over PivotItems and change visibility. It happens because you must leave one item visible at all times. The workaround is to set the first item to visible, do the loop, and then check whether the first item should be visible or not. Of course, this won't help you if the thing you're looking for isn't in the PivotTable, which might be the case here. It may well be that (CDate(pfiPivFldItem.Value) will never equal CLng(dtmDate)) due to the issue/bug I outlined at http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2013/11/09/a-date-with-pivotitems/

There's some other things you want to do when filtering PivotTables, such as switch the PivotTable .ManualUpdate property to TRUE while you loop the PivotTable, or otherwise the PT will try to update after each and every change.

Suggest you check out my answer at [Filter pivot table 1004 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48463674/filter-pivot-table-1004-error/48489988#48489988) as the code comments show how and why to do some of this stuff. Also suggest you check out my blogpost at http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2013/11/14/filtering-pivots-based-on-external-ranges/ that takes an indepth look at bottlenecks and workarounds when iterating over PivotItems.

Note that the quickest way to filter a field on one item is to make it a PageField, and set the .PageField value to the PivotItem concerned. That's near instantaneous, and makes a massive difference if you have thousands of items in the PivotField that you're iterating over.